# iPhone - issue in playing mp4 video with Swift - iOS

Tags: ios, swift, nsurl

I used this code to ready the path of the mp4 file from resources and play it.

I used this code snippet:

```
func playVideo(videoName : String, type: String) {


    let url = urlForFile(videoName, fileType: type)
    if let url = url {
        /* use the scene */
        moviePlayer = MPMoviePlayerController(contentURL: url)
        if let player = moviePlayer {
            player.view.frame = self.view.bounds

            player.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyle.None
            player.prepareToPlay()
            player.scalingMode = .AspectFill
            self.view.addSubview(player.view)
        }
        println("it started!")
    } else {
        /* the scene couldn't be intialized */
        finishedVideo()
    }

}

func urlForFile (fileName : String, fileType: String) -> NSURL? {
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(fileName, ofType:fileType)
    if let path = path {
        return NSURL(fileURLWithPath:path)
    } else {
        return nil
    }
}
```

i implement it with this function call:

```
playVideo("splash_video", type: "mp4");
```

the file is here:

[image: Screenshot]

the `urlForFile` function always returns `nil`

I also tried to convert the video to m4v and mov, still get same result "**nil**"

so how on earth Can i play video in SWIFT !?

Comment: Did you added the target membership ?

Comment: @MidhunMP you mean the splash_video.mp4 file ?

Comment: Yes, I think you didn't added that file to your target membership.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code looks correct, there is no issue in that. Probably you forgot to add that file to your target membership.

1. Select your file
2. Choose the file inspector
3. Under Target Membership select your target

[image: Target]

Comment: I think this is valid only for video files, because i added images and automatically they were added as targets

Comment: @MBH No it's for all files (including source file). When you add a file to project, in the file chooser it'll show a similar option to choose targets.